# Letter closing for the cover letter

Tags: cover-letter

Does closing my cover-letter with salutations or closing phrases like *sincerely yours* or *yours truly* make it look like an email? If so, how best to close the letter?

Comment: Why would using a closing that is only ever used for paper letters, and never used for email, make your cover letter sound like an email?

Comment: What about "_Thank you for your time,_" or "_Thank you for your consideration,_" ?

Comment: I was always taught to use 'Yours faithfully' in cases where you have not met/do not know the person to whom you are writing the letter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Sincerely,` seems like it would be appropriate just about anywhere.

`Sincerely yours`, or `Yours truly` definitely do not sound appropriate. You would use those in a personal communication to someone that you're close with/to.

Comment: You could probably use *Regards, * as well.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I started writing letters before email was a thing. "Sincerely" and "Very truly yours" were appropriate ways to end a business letter.

If they make it look like email to you, that's because you have been taught that emails should look like business letters.

Go for it.

Comment: This is a cover "letter" not an email - you would normally attach two documents here

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are writing a full cover letter ie a direct pitch as to why you meet their requirements.

The formal way in English is:

"Yours sincerely" when you know the person you are addressing, 
"Yours faithfully" when you are starting your letter with Dear Sir/Madam, etc

If you mean just a five to ten line email with a word or pdf attachment - you could use the above or Just "Best Regards"